# iOS keyboard dismiss and then immediately show

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextview, uialertview

I have UIViewController with UITextView. This TextView always firstResponder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createBottomBar];
    _textView.delegate = self;
    [_textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

When user tap "video" button my app show UIAlertView with textfield

```
- (IBAction)showVideoPicker:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:_(@"Link to movie")
        message:_(@"Insert a link to YouTube clip or a Coub")
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:_(@"Cancel")
        otherButtonTitles:_(@"Attach"), nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}
```

When user tap "Attach" button alert dismiss and keyboard dismiss and then immediately show. I would like another scenario: keyboard do not dismiss, because text view should always be a first responder. Just UIAlertView dismiss wihout keyboard dismiss/show animation.

For more understanding see gif [here](https://ps.vk.me/c539200/u12823027/docs/7d6a3b9c9876/scrn.gif?extra=ewN7EHalAa5i9VrSzZhH8jE0hkrp_wkyWlZupSvOCrsoGPPomJ4Lfrk3QQngTXnUrDkDNiMJLUsqLSNJnnMZLGmnm2gSgQ) (do not have enough reputation to post images). Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the first responder on the Attach button tap via `UIAlertView` delegate? It's the only way here:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) [_textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

The keyboard might or might not jump a little, but that's all we have.